# ScopeCompile expects variables to already exist, doesn't that negate the whole point?

Tags: c#, eval, csharpeval

I'm using [CSharpEval's ScopeCompile](https://csharpeval.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Performance&referringTitle=Documentation) functionality to allow me to re-use a compiled expression on different data:

```
        var exp = new CompiledExpression<int>("a.Count");
        var func = exp.ScopeCompile();
```

But I get this exception in the `ScopeCompile` call:

> An exception of type
>   'ExpressionEvaluator.Parser.ExpressionParseException' occurred in
>   ExpressionEvaluator.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Cannot resolve symbol "a" at line 1 char 0

I don't understand what is happening. The example in my link allows caching of scope-compiled expressions and what use is it if the varaibles in my expression already have to exist when compiling the expression?!

The documentation is pretty limited and this area of C# is not one I understand well enough to just read the source code easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try following,

```
public class ScopeContext<TArg,TRet>{

    public dynamic Scope {get;set;}

    public Func<TArg,TRet> Expression;

    public ScopeContext(string exp){
        TypeRegistry tr = new TypeRegistry();
        tr.RegisterSymbole("scope",Scope);

        Expression = (new CompiledExpression<TRet>(exp)
        {
            TypeRegistry = tr
        }).ScopeCompile<TArg>();
    }

}

// usage

ScopeContext<object,object> f = 
     new ScopeContext<object,object>("scope.Count");


// you can now change scope dynamically...
f.Scope = new List<int>();

var result = f.Expression(null);
```

Comment: I'm confused how I can re-use this compiled expression with different data if I have to provide the data at compile-time? In the linked example `GetCachedFunction` how is this working? I'm not sure if the documentation is bad or if I'm just missing something fundamental?!

Comment: @Mr.Boy how do you intend to pass "a" ? What he means by `GetCachedFunction` is you don't need to call `ScopeCompile` as it is cpu intensive operation. You can store `func` in your cache to invoke same expression.